# itemclick listener for recyclerview in android

Tags: android

I am using android recyclerview with cardview, which populates with the data from server. I want to set itemclick event for each item and need to display a dialog with a text. this text also getting from server. it will be different for diferent items.

when I am trying like given,

```
 mItem=lists.getRemarks();
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new SweetAlertDialog(v.getContext())
                    .setTitleText("Remark")
                    .setContentText(mItem)
                    .show();
        }
    });
```

it only gives the last details

Comment: Set the click listener in your view holder

Comment: thank you for your answer...... i solved it ..

Comment: if you solved your problem by your self then write you fix as answer so it will not take time of others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

somehow i solved it by setting **setContentText(mItem)** to **setContentText(lists.getRemarks())**

Answer (score 1):

`Recyclerview` does not have its item click listener so I have one `custom class` to detect it

**RecyclerItemClickListner**

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener
{
    public static interface OnItemClickListener
    {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
        public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener)
    {
        mListener = listener;

        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)
            {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e)
            {
                View childView = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

                if(childView != null && mListener != null)
                {
                    mListener.onItemLongClick(childView, recyclerView.getChildPosition(childView));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e)
    {
        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

        if(childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e))
        {
            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildPosition(childView));
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent){}

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}
```

**Use it**

```
 mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), mRecyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
               // do whatever you want on position clicked 
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
              // do whatever you want on position long press
            }
        }));
```